# PHP $filename with text

Tags: php, post, filenames

Quick question (hopefully)

I am saving a form as a pdf using php and would like to save the $filename as something like:

**/New_Form_[user].pdf**

(where [user] is **$POST['forename']+$POST['surname']**)

Is this possible? if so how?

my current code:

```
$filename = "HTC_619 New User.pdf";
```

The "New User" bit i want auto populated from Firstname and Surname from the form.

so:

```
$filename = "HTC_619_$POST['Forename']_$POST['Surname']
```

Thanks

Phil

Comment: ok great answer.... how?

Comment: He answered the question you asked. SO is not a free tutorial guide.

Comment: quick Answer(hopefully) yes possible @Philb24

Comment: Ok apologies, been a long day, can someone explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it like

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"")
$filename = "HTC_619". $username."_".$surname.".pdf";
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite what i am looking for... I need to edit the filename to save as "New Form for $post['firstname']['lastname']

Answer (score 0):

pass the post first name and last name in $filename variable

```
 $name=$_POST['forename']+$_POST['surname'];
 $filename="htc_619"."_".$name.".pdf";
```